# How to implement Custom cropping using golang

Tags: image, go, image-processing, image-manipulation, imaging

Am looking to do custom cropping on a set of images, Instead of cropping normally, using height and width i want the flexibility of getting an output image that is cropped like a polygon or an hexagon for example, Am using the library `github.com/fogleman/gg`, and the built in module "image", and `github.com/disintegration/imaging`, but I didn't find a way to customize the cropping, i also looked for an online SaaS to do this, like imgix or imageresizer.io, but they don't seem to offer that, i know golang is the right language for this maybe i didn't look hard enough, please Help

my sample Code looks like:

```golang
var image image.Image
dc := NewContext(1000, 1000)
image = imaging.Fill(profile, 800, 750, imaging.Center, imaging.Lanczos)
// Cropping needs to happen here
dc.DrawImage(image, 123, 250)
```

Comment: What happens to the part that's outside the crop? Images can only have a rectangular shape. Do you intend to fill it with a transparent background? i.e. a PNG or something?

Comment: Yes exactly, it's a PNG file that will have a transparent background after being cropped like a polygon

Comment: So, you want a specific shape? Each shape has to be computed in a different way

Comment: The docs of `github.com/fogleman/gg` say its clipping functions work on paths, and it mentions a set of functions to create such paths. So, [what have you tried?](https://www.whathaveyoutried.com/).

Comment: Added a little solution, let me know if it doesn't work :)

Answer (score 2):

A bit longer than expected but here you have PNG image cropping with transparent background to a rectangle. You can modify the code for different shapes by changing the `getPixAlpha` function.

Just add the package name and it should include the imports, then add an image `test.png` and it should create a `test-output.png`

Note: You may want to make some minor modifications for using it as a service.

```
type Pixel struct {
    R int
    G int
    B int
    A int
}

func LogPanic(err error, msg string) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("ERROR: %v %s", err, msg)
        panic(err)
    }
}

func getPixAlpha(x, y, halfWidth int) int {
    if x < halfWidth-y || x > halfWidth+y {
        return 0
    }
    if y > halfWidth+x {
        return 0
    }
    if x > halfWidth*3-y && y > halfWidth*3-x {
        return 0
    }
    return int(255)
}

func getPixels(file io.Reader) ([][]Pixel, error) {
    img, _, err := image.Decode(file)
    LogPanic(err, "error reading image")
    bounds := img.Bounds()
    width, height := bounds.Max.X, bounds.Max.Y
    var pixels [][]Pixel
    for x := 0; x < width; x++ {
        var row []Pixel
        for y := 0; y < height; y++ {
            row = append(row, rgbaToPixel(img.At(x, y).RGBA()))
        }
        pixels = append(pixels, row)
    }
    return pixels, nil
}

func rgbaToPixel(r uint32, g uint32, b uint32, a uint32) Pixel {
    return Pixel{int(r / 257), int(g / 257), int(b / 257), int(a / 257)}
}

func getRgbaPic(pixels [][]Pixel) [][]Pixel {
    dx := len(pixels)
    dy := len(pixels[0])
    for x := 0; x < dx; x++ {
        for y := 0; y < dy; y++ {
            pixels[x][y].A = getPixAlpha(x, y, len(pixels)/2)
        }
    }
    return pixels
}

func main() {
    file, err := os.Open("./test.png")
    LogPanic(err, "Error opening file")
    defer file.Close()
    pixels, err := getPixels(file)
    LogPanic(err, "Error reading image")
    pixels = getRgbaPic(pixels)
    img := image.NewRGBA(image.Rect(0, 0, len(pixels), len(pixels[0])))
    for x := 0; x < len(pixels); x++ {
        for y := 0; y < len(pixels[0]); y++ {
            img.Set(x, y, color.RGBA{
                uint8(pixels[x][y].R),
                uint8(pixels[x][y].G),
                uint8(pixels[x][y].B),
                uint8(pixels[x][y].A),
            })
        }
    }
    buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
    err = png.Encode(buf, img)
    LogPanic(err, "Error encoding")
    err = ioutil.WriteFile("test-output.png", buf.Bytes(), 0666)
    LogPanic(err, "Error writing file")
}
```

Comment: I'll test this and get back to you asap! much appreciated